# Find row number based on value r

Tags: r, dataframe

How do you find the row numbers associated with a specific text string?

I need the function to return [1] 1 2 3 4 from the dataset below.

RowNumber Name 
1 Diet Pepsi 
2 Pepsi Max 
3 Diet Pepsi 20 oz 
4 Pepsi 
5 Coca-Cola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for "Pepsi" ?

`which(grepl("Pepsi", dataset$Name))`